# How to define current date with yaml in OpenERP?

Tags: datetime, yaml, openerp-7

I want to create the demo data on my module and use `yaml` to do this
and my problem is i want to create the current date on my demo

in xml

```
<field name="date_invoice" eval="time.strftime('%Y')+'-06-23'"/>
```

and my question is if i want to put in yaml what can i do ?
*Some one please help me and thank you for you time to rend my word (sorry about my language :'|)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
field_date: !eval time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

or if you want defined day code like this

```
field_date: !eval time.strftime('%Y-%m-24')
```